# WKWebView detect login page change or re-direction

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-environment

I have a swift WKWebView app with user authentication, the app allows users to register their devices by collecting the device's vendor id. When a user runs the mobile app, it will check if the mobile device is registered then validates the login details associated with the registered device. All good so far.

My problem is that when the PHP session expires, users will be re-directed to the login page. If the user closes the app and re-open it, it will log the user without having to re-enter the login details. PHP session time-out can not be changed due to company policy.

I would like to know if I could detect the login page URL change and send the device vendor id with the login page URL similar to the app startup process. So, when the PHP session expires, users will be automatically logged back in without having to re-enter their login credentials.

Here is the current code I am using and this is my first IOS app, and I have very limited experience when it comes to mobile programming and I have been searching for the last couple of day without any luck. Sample codes are highly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // get device vendor id
        let mystring = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        let webUrl = "https://www.mydomain/login/" + mystring
        
        let myURL = URL(string: webUrl)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)` method of `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol to detect if `URL` has changed to login `URL` and perform the required task to manually log out the user, example., by deleting the `vendor id` that you've stored.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    //...
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        if let urlString = navigationResponse.response.url?.absoluteString {
            print(urlString)
            // check if urlString == "loginUrl" and perform required task here
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```